# How to insert while loop data of php in jQuery array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, while-loop

I want to insert while loop user data in jQuery array.

```
<?php 

    while($get_users_table_details = mysql_fetch_array($deatails)) {


        if(empty($get_users_table_details["photo"])) { $pics = "photos/avatar.gif"; } else { $pics = "photos/".strip_tags($get_users_table_details["photo"]).""; }

        ?>
```

Script code between while loop

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#full").mention({
            users: [{
                name: '<?php echo $get_users_table_details['fullname'];?>',
                username: '<?php echo $get_users_table_details['username'];?>',
                image: '<?php echo $pics;?>'
                   }]     });
});
    </script>

end of script

}
end of while loop
```

The problem is that this shows the user details of only one user. However, I want all user details to be shown, as in this picture:

[image]

Comment: You should iterate loop into javascript code instead of PHP code. And need to push every element into users javascript array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Please provide your PHP array data structure.

Comment: id, username,  pic, full name,

Comment: build the users array completely in php, then json_encode the whole thing and 'pass' it to js. Get the javascript out of the while loop.

Comment: _and_: do not use `mysql_*` functions any more. They are old, deprecated, unsecure and removed in the latest php version. Use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first build the array of users in php:

```
<?php

$users = []; // instatiate an empty array

while($get_users_table_details = mysql_fetch_array($deatails)) {
    // build a user-array as needed later
    $user = [];
    $user['name'] = $get_users_table_details['fullname'];
    $user['username'] = $get_users_table_details['username'];
    if(empty($get_users_table_details["photo"])) { 
         $user['image'] = "photos/avatar.gif"; 
    } else { 
         $user['image'] = "photos/".strip_tags($get_users_table_details["photo"]); 
    }
    $users[] = $user;  // add this user to the array of users
}
?>
```

Then pass (=echo) that to javascript via json_encode:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#full").mention({
        users: <?php echo json_encode($users); ?>
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sample javascript code.

```
    var users = <?php echo json_encode($get_users_table_details ) ?>;
    $.each(users, function(key, value) {
        console.log('stuff : ' + key + ", " + value);
        // Do everything you want
    });
```